# Apply Dense to every output in RNN Layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to convert the following Keras code into pure Tensorflow but I have trouble adding a dense layer to every timestep of the bidirectional RNN output:

Here is the Keras code in question:

```
self.model = Sequential()
self.model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(nr_out, return_sequences=True,
                                     dropout_W=dropout, dropout_U=dropout),
                                     input_shape=(max_length, nr_out)))
self.model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(nr_out, activation='relu', init='he_normal')))
self.model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
```

Here is the initial tensorflow code:

```
lstm_cell_fwd = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
lstm_cell_bwd = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
outputs, output_state_fw, output_state_bw  = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_cell_fwd, lstm_cell_bwd, inputs=sequence, dtype=tf.float64)
```

Generally if I only wanted to predict on the last state I would do something like:

```
logits = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

What is the best way to express the TimeDistributed layer in Tensorflow?

Comment: It could be worth it to look at the `keras.layers.wrappers` source ( https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/wrappers.py ). `TimeDistributed` and `Bidirectional` are the first two `wrappers` in the source. Try mimicking how they accomplish the task.

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as correct so that people know what worked for you when the have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your cell definition to something like:

```py
lstm_cell_fwd = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
lstm_cell_fwd = rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell_fwd, input_keep_prob=dropout, output_keep_prob=dropout)  # if you want to keep dropout, which seems to be in your Keras model
lstm_cell_fwd = rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(lstm_cell_fwd, nr_out)  # FC output layer
# Similarly for lstm_cell_bwd
outputs, output_state_fw, output_state_bw  = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_cell_fwd, lstm_cell_bwd, ...)
```

It looks like your Keras definition uses dropout, so I added a dropout layer here. I believe the `dropout_W` from Keras is equivalent to `input_keep_prob` in TF, and `dropout_U` from Keras is `output_keep_prob` in TF. For your dropout layer, you would need to define a placeholder:

```py
dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [], name='dropout')
```

and feed that when you run your network with some dropout probability for training, and usually `dropout=1.0` for validation, testing, and using the network.